# Updating all columns that has same title but have different ids

Tags: php

I have a table named collection and has columns like title,author,edition,volume, etc. Now, i want to be able to update all columns that has been edited with the same title but have different ids.

here is my example code

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","library03");
    $check="SELECT * FROM collection WHERE title = '$_POST[title]'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
    if($data[0] > 1) {
        for($i=0;$i<=COUNT($data);$i++){
        $sql="UPDATE collection SET author = '$new_author' WHERE title = '$_POST[title]'";
        $sql_connect = mysqli_query($sql);
```

And these are under my $_POST

```
$collection = Collection::find_by_id($_POST['id']);
    $collection->date_received      = $_POST['date_received'];
    $collection->title              = $_POST['title'];
    $collection->author             = $_POST['author'];
    $collection->edition            = $_POST['edition'];
    $collection->volume             = $_POST['volume'];
    $collection->pages              = $_POST['pages'];
    $collection->cost               = $_POST['cost'];
    $collection->publisher          = $_POST['publisher'];
    $collection->pub_year           = $_POST['pub_year'];
    $collection->remarks            = $_POST['remarks'];
    $collection->call_number        = $_POST['call_number'];
    $collection->col_copy           = $_POST['col_copy'];
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: How can i update columns that have same title? example i want to change the author of a book that has 3 copies. if i edit one book, the 2 books will also be edited

Comment: what do you want man. I'm still not getting. So, do you want to update other 2 books also or not ?

Comment: yes i want to update the other 2 books

Comment: but its ok now thanks btw